# Javascript string objects not displayed in the Visual Studio 2010 Intellisence

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-2010

I'm newbie to javascript. Actually I tried getting the element name by ID

**HTML:-**

```
<img id ="img" src="Images/GoogleLogo.gif" onclick="changeImage()" alt="Google" width="100" height="180" />
```

**Javascript:-**

```
var image = document.getElementById('img').src;
console.log(image);// returns a string
```

So the above code is returning a string,

So I thought of using the string functions like `match(), substring() etc..`Just for my learning purpose. The Javascript string functions are not displayed in the visual studio 2010 IDE..

My question is

1) Hence it is returning a string object, then why can't I able to use the In-built Javascript string functions?

2) Why it is not shown in the visual studio 2010 Intellisence?

[image: Javascript string functions]

Comment: Did you visit : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385682.aspx ?

Answer (score 0):

You wont get those always in VS.
One option to improve JavaScript experience in Visual Studio you need to install the JScript Extensions.
In VS -> Tools -> Extension Manager -> Search for JScript

Here you can find few. ( Resharper 6.1 , Free JS Editor, etc..)

Or 
Even if you know the function name ( say eg- for string these sunstring, length,...) you can directly write down, EVEN IF its not showing as Intellisence - It will work ( as long the browser supports those)